# On a Proof of Jointly Typical Sequences Using Chebyshev's Inequality

Tags: probability-theory, information-theory

My lecturer went through the topic of "Jointly Typical Sequences" in my Information Theory course, and one of the properties/lemma was that $P((X^n, Y^n) \in A^{(n)}_e) \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$, where $A^{(n)}_e$ is the typical set.

He went on to prove that 
$P((X^n, Y^n) \notin A^
{(n)}_\epsilon) \le P(E_x) + P(E_y) + P(E_{xy})$, where

$E_x = {|-\frac{1}{n}logP(x^n) - H(X)| > \epsilon},$

$E_y = {|-\frac{1}{n}logP(y^n) - H(Y)| > \epsilon},$

$E_{xy} = {|-\frac{1}{n}logP(x^n y^n) - H(XY)| > \epsilon}$

By Chebyshev's Inequality, $P(E_x) \to 0$, $P(E_y) \to 0$ and $P(E_{xy}) \to 0$, hence, completing the proof.

I don't understand why $P(E_x) \to 0$, $P(E_y) \to 0$ and $P(E_{xy}) \to 0$ using Chebyshev's Inequality. I know that Chebyshev's Inequality states that

$P(|X - E(X)| > \epsilon) <= Var(X)/\epsilon^2$

I could take the log probabilities as $X$ and the entropies as $E[X]$ in the Chebyshev's Inequality. However, I would need the variance to be zero for $P(E_x) \to 0$, $P(E_y) \to 0$ and $P(E_{xy}) \to 0$. This is what I don't get - where does the variance come from and why does it go to zero? Or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: Actually the [Weak Law of Large Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers) is in work here. The use of Chebychev's inequality is required to establish the WLLN for i.i.d. random variables. In fact a stonger result holds which says almost sure convergence by SLLN.

Comment: Yeah, the Cover and Thomas book uses the WLLN, which I understand, although I thought using $\epsilon/3$ as the bound for $E_x$, $E_y$ and $E_{xy}$ was a bit arbitrary just so they could sum up to $\epsilon$, but it's something I have to get used to in mathematical proofs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement follows by observing that $X$ in you case is an average value. If you assume (I guess you did that) that the sequence is independent and identically distributed, then

\begin{align}
X&=-\frac{1}{n}\log P(x^n)\\
&=-\frac{1}{n}\log \left( \prod_{i=1}^n p(x_i)\right)\\
&= -\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \log p(x_i)
\end{align}

which is the average of $n$ independently and identically distributed random variables. Hence, the variance of $X$ scales with $1/n$.

Comment: Really? I don't think so. $Var(A+B)=Var(A)+Var(B)$ if $A$ and $B$ are independent, and $Var(nA)=n^2Var(A)$ for scalar $n$. If you combine these two, you get $Var(X)=1/n\cdot Var(\log p(Y))$, where $Y$ is distributed according to $p$.